# Why is the dir command not working?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, virtualization, iso-image

I can see that the file is there and I can mount it with virtual clonedrive and play it with powerdvd:
[image]

But windows can't find the file:

```
C:\>dir dead*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3EAA-B7A4

 Directory of C:\

File Not Found

C:\>
```

Why is Windows 7 not working?

### Update

The only programs that can view the ISO are Virtual CloneDrive and DVDDecrypter. In Windows Explorer the ISO doesn't show up, but when I converted the ISo to VOBs the VOBs showed up. Can it have something to do with a vary large file in the root directory? Nah...If at all related, there are error message from DVDDecrypter when closing the ISo but that is when closing and those message are difficult to understand like "invalid data format" or likewise.

Comment: Unmount the ISO.

Comment: Have you tried dir DEAD*

Comment: try "dir DEAD*.*" or "dir DEAD*.ISO"

Comment: and "dir *.ISO" ;)

Comment: @soandos: Windows is (for all general usage) case-insensitive.

Comment: I can only reach the file via DVDDecrypter and ElbySoft VirtuaDrive but via those program I can facilitate another backup to a directory C:\DEADMAUS_TORONTO\ and convert the ISO to VOBs etc for further treatment. Thanks a lot for the comments. Now I have the VOBs and those kind of files instead of the ISo and those files are viewable in internet explorer and I can continue with the VOBs after converting the ISO to \VIDEO_TS\*.*

Comment: does it show up if you just do a plain `dir`?

Comment: @techie007 Nope. It's sort of strange that it won't. Could it be something with that the file is large and in the root directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not already doing that, you could try running the same command from an [elevated command prompt](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/783-elevated-command-prompt.html).

Maybe the ISO has some special permissions, and you're running Virtual CloneDrive and DVDDecrypter as an administrator, which allows them to "see" that file.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll try this a.s.a.p. and report back.

Answer (score 2):

It might be due too specific attributes added to the file.

Check if `dir /A dead*` will pick it up.

Also you might want to try `dir /A | FIND /I "DEAD"`

The icon of the file seems to have a lock - this is due to specific permission setup for this file and/or ownership of it. Check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17117/remove-the-lock-icon-from-a-folder-in-windows-7/) article how to get rid of it. I think this is the cause of dir failing to find this file.

Comment: Yep, the file could be hidden but Windows could be set to show all hidden files.

Comment: It didn't show up and doesn't in explorer either. But it does show up in DVDDecrypter which has a dialog from which a can mount and view the iso with powerdvd. Oddly enough.

Comment: The icon of the file seems to have a lock - this is due to specific permission setup for this file and/or ownership of it. Check this article how to get rid of it : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17117/remove-the-lock-icon-from-a-folder-in-windows-7/ . i think this is the cause of dir failing to find this file.

Comment: @mnmnc Thanks for all the help. It's not very necessary for me that this very file works but I want the procedure to work making it easy to backup a DVD without actually spending a disc but ripping it to ISO format.